# how to include pyarmor in nuitka

Tags: python, exe, nuitka, pyarmor

Let's say we have 2 files:
mainfile.py

```
from modulefile import x
x()
```

modulefile.py

```
def x():
    print("Working!")
```

how can I obfuscate these two files and include it in nuitka as a onefile executable?

I tried it once but it told things like `name '__pyarmor__' is not defined` or `no module named modulefile`

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy pytransform folder to nuitka's executable path. Pyarmor needs to pytransform folder (and DLL inside of it) to run.

Comment: yeah I fixed it already, thanks anyways!